# Problems with Internet via home WiFi, mobile data and other WiFis work fine

Tags: wi-fi, internet

I'm having various problems with two Android phones in my home WiFi: from time to time, the phones

- can't connect to the WiFi at all (despite stored credentials) -- happens only rarely
- can connect, but get no Internet access via the WiFi (e.g. right now I'm getting `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET`, but the another time it might be a different one) -- happens more often (say once every two weeks)
- can connect and get Internet access, but with a big lag (DNS lookups and/or establishing connections is very slow, once connected the bandwidth is fine) -- *happens always*

At the same time, the phones work fine with mobile data and other WiFis. Similarly, the home WiFi works well with our laptops. It seems that there is something problematic in the specific combination of these specific phones and that specific WiFi.

Workarounds that I've tried and that sometimes (but not always) work:

- Disconnecting and reconnecting to the WiFi
- Disabling and re-enabling the WiFi on the phones
- Rebooting the phone
- Removing the stored credentials for the WiFi from the phones
- Resetting the WiFi access point

One of the phones is an Lenovo C2 (K10a40) running Android 6.0, the other one is a Samsung S4 mini Gt-i9195 also running Android 6.0.

The WiFi access point is a TP-Link TL-WR841N/ND v9 running OpenWrt/LEDE Reboot 17.01.4. The WiFi is using WPA2 PSK encryption and automatic channel selection.

I've checked other similar threads on android.SE, but none of them suggest anything that I haven't already tried.

**What are possible reasons and solutions for these problems?**

Comment: This sounds like more of a problem with the router itself. Have you got any other routers on hand to try?

Comment: @MoonRunestar unfortunately no. Since the router works fine with the laptops I was hoping to avoid getting a new one. But if everything else fails then this is indeed a good idea.

Comment: If the problem occur are always both phones affected?

Comment: @Robert From my experiences, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Please check what type of wifi your router broadcasts. If it broadcasts both 2.5Ghz and 5Ghz your phone may discover the 5Ghz network, try to connect to it but then has no "power" to stay on that type of network and falls. So make sure your device is connecting to the 2.5Ghz network.

Comment: 2.4GHz and 5GHz usually broadcast on separate SSIDs. If you don't want the device to randomly switch between the two, you can just select Forget on one of them (preferably the 2.4GHz one as that is the less reliable of the two).